# Drupal 8 page.html.twig per content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there any way to make custom page.html.twig for custom content type for example
page--node--content-type.html.twig?

currently we get
page--node--%.html.twig...

Answer (score 2):

Put below code to your *theme_name.theme* file

```
function theme_name_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__'.$content_type;
  }
}
```

Then for 'custom' content type you can create 'page--custom.html.twig' file.

Comment: what is the url of your "page--custom.html.twig"?